# Without each How to find element having attribute value in set of Array in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having one Array permissionID and `div` elements on page having attribute `permissionID`.

```
var permissionID = ["20", "21", "22"];
```

I want to search all the div element having `permissionID` among provided array without using loop or each.

Output: *All the Div having at least one permission ID of this given array.*

Comment: Share the HTML.

Comment: What do you mean "without using loop or each"?  Pretty much any search function you call will use a loop under the covers.  This seems like a very arbitrary requirement

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate the array to create a valid selector string for [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) in conjunction with [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```js
var permissionID = ["20", "21", "22"];
var selector = permissionID.map(function(p) {
  return 'div[permissionID="' + p + '"]';
}).join(',');
console.log(selector);

//Get elements
//    var elements = $(selector);
```